Cordova-ios 7.1.0: ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration after adding privacy manifest
I’m updating all of my apps to target the new versions of all the plugins we use, and for some reason, I have a warning message :

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “*****” file references one or more APIs that require reasons,
including the following API categories:
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. ...
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “*****” file references one or more APIs that require reasons,
including the following API categories:
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. ...
Apple Developer Relations

But in my Cordova config.xml, I have already added the <privacy-manifest> tag:
<privacy-manifest>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <false/>
    
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array/>
            
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDomains</key>
    <array/>
            
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
              
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>E174.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
                    
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>3B52.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</privacy-manifest>

I have already sent some applications to Apple, and there is no problem, they haven’t sent me back the ‘Missing API declaration’ error.
So in conclusion, I don’t know what the problem is for three of my app’s pool. it’s been several days that I’ve been working on this issue.
If you have a solution, please let me know.
env :

cordova-ios : 7.1.0
xcode : 15.3
macos : 14.4.1

Best regards."
I am trying to get Apple’s review of 3 of my applications among a mobile application park on the App Store Connect. Unfortunately, they pass with a warning.
The problem is that the privacy manifest is apparently not read because it receives this email with this warning ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration.
I need to understand why all my other applications did not receive this email while the plugins are at the same version, and the compilation is the same. More simply, I am in the same development environment

You might have a special character like '&' in your config.xml of your app.

Yes, thank you, that was my problem, I've already solved it but forgot to update. Some of my apps had '&amp' in their title tag.
